# Calculator operating with last result instead of new value

Tags: ios, objective-c, calculator

I know this question is very specific but believe it to be helpful to anyone wanting to learn the ways an Objective-C calculator works.

The app works this way: a number is pressed;

```
- (IBAction)numberButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    //Resets label after calculations are shown from previous operations
    if (isMainLabelTextTemporary)
    {
        (mainLabel.text = @"0");
        isMainLabelTextTemporary = NO;
    }

    NSString *numString = ((UIButton*)sender).titleLabel.text;

    //Get the string from the button label and main label
    mainLabel.text = [mainLabelString stringByAppendingFormat:numString];
}
```

an operand is pressed,

```
- (IBAction)operandPressed:(id)sender
{ 
    //Calculate from previous operand
    [self calculate];

    //Get the NEW operand from the button pressed
    operand = ((UIButton*)sender).titleLabel.text;
}
```

another number is pressed, when equals is pressed the three are calculated into the result;

```
- (IBAction)equalsPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self calculate];

    //reset operand
    operand = @"";
}
```

The calculate method being

```
- (void)calculate
{
//Get the current value on screen 
    double currentValue = [mainLabel.text doubleValue]; 

// If we already have a value stored and the current # is not 0, operate the values 
    if (lastKnownValue != 0 && currentValue != 0)
    {
        if ([operand isEqualToString:@"+"])
            lastKnownValue += currentValue;
        else if ([operand isEqualToString:@"-"])
            lastKnownValue -= currentValue;
        else if ([operand isEqualToString:@"×"])
            lastKnownValue *= currentValue;
        else if ([operand isEqualToString:@"/"])
            lastKnownValue /= currentValue;

        else if ([operand isEqualToString:@"xʸ"])
            lastKnownValue = (pow(lastKnownValue, currentValue));

        else if ([operand isEqualToString:@"ʸ√x"])
            lastKnownValue = (pow(lastKnownValue, 1.0/currentValue));
   }  

    else
        lastKnownValue = currentValue;

    //Set the new value to the main label
    mainLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%F", lastKnownValue];

    isMainLabelTextTemporary = YES;
}
```

and clear

```
- (IBAction)clearPressed:(id)sender
{
    lastKnownValue = 0;
    mainLabel.text = @"0";
    isMainLabelTextTemporary = NO;
    operand = @"";
}
```

Calculating works fine and the result is displayed correctly. If then you press `clear` and calculate something else no problems occur but, if after a result is displayed one tries just entering another number and then calculating with it, it is instead done with the last result.
Went over the code many times, tried setting up `NSLogs` to monitor the values constantly but had no luck finding the mistake, what is amiss?

**EDIT**, solution: As implied in Wain's answer, the solution is resetting `lastKnownValue`, doing so after the result is calculated and displayed, by setting it to 0 so that the code overwrites it when the new one is entered:

```
- (IBAction)equalsPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self calculate];

    //reset operand
    operand = @"";

    //reset lastKnownValue
    lastKnownValue = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you don't clear the last set `operand` still exists and the `lastKnownValue` and `currentValue` will both exist (because one is new and one is the previous result).

I guess the confusion is because you are triggering a calculation from `operandPressed:` so the calculation is continued 'mid-flow'.

Consider the possibility of building up the entire calculation entered by the user and processing it as a whole rather than completing each part individually and modifying the value of `lastKnownValue` (obviously your ability to do this depends on the interface you want to present to the users).

Comment: many thanks! Understand, will try and report outcomes as soon as I can!

Comment: great! yes, will make it all simpler by making all the buttons and numbers into a single formula string soon! thanks again :)

Comment: Look at `NSExpression` and what it can do to help you.

Comment: I edited your answer to add the solution explicitly, why isn't it updated?

Comment: Your edit was rejected by the community (because it's generally trying to comment on the existing answer).